# Iterating an array inside of an array, in iterated component in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, loops, angular-reactive-forms, behaviorsubject

I have made a component that is iterated by an array. Then the data inside of that array is being pushed into each iterated component. I am able to display data from the array, but unable to display data from an array that is inside of the array.

Here is an example of the data:

```
[
  {
    "questionArray": [
      {
        "questionText": "How many cats do you have? ",
        "questionId": "",
        "questionControlTypeId": "",
        "questionSequence": "",
        "imageUrl": null,
        "quizId": "",
        "isEditing": false,
        "questionAnswers": [
          {
            "answer": "1",
            "correctAnswer": false,
            "questionAnswerId": "",
            "questionId": "",
            "sortOrder": ""
          },
          {
            "answer": "3",
            "correctAnswer": false,
            "questionAnswerId": null,
            "questionId": null,
            "sortOrder": null
          },
          {
            "answer": "4",
            "correctAnswer": false,
            "questionAnswerId": null,
            "questionId": null,
            "sortOrder": null
          },
          {
            "answer": "5",
            "correctAnswer": false,
            "questionAnswerId": null,
            "questionId": null,
            "sortOrder": null
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "id": 1
  } ]
```

There is more than one object of this data.
Here's what I'm attempting to do with it.

```
<div *ngFor="let example of exampleArray$">
  <div *ngFor="let ex of example.nestedData">
    <example-component
      exampleQuestion="{{ex.questionText}}"
      exampleAnswer="{{ex.questionAnswers}}"
    ></example-component>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then I'm using @Input in my TS file for "example-component" to get that data and use it in the HTML.

```
@Input() exampleQuestion;
@Input() exampleAnswer;
```

I'm using {{questionText}} to display my text, and it's working just fine.

The issue is with "questionAnswers". Which itself is an array, and not only is it an array, it's also going to be used on a reactive form that has dynamic controls.

```
<div *ngFor="let htmlexample of questionAnswers">
  --this would be where my dynamic input field is--
<div>
```

However, instead of getting back multiple fields, I am getting this error:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

I am also getting [object Object] in my console.logs.

My console.log of my observable (which is being maintained by BehaviorSubject) is logging the array appropriately.

Thank you in advance for any insight on this issue.

Comment: Is "let htmlexample of questionAnswers" inside the example-component?

Comment: if you are using an observable on the html, you should use | async as well

Comment: @CaioOliveira I've tried using the async pipe, but when I do, I get an InvalidPipeArgument.

Comment: @JeffreyRam Yes, sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need interpolation **{{ }}** and you should use property binding **[ ]** to bind the exampleQuestion and exampleAnswer to *ex.questionText* and *ex.questionAnswers* respectively. Try

```
<example-component
  [exampleQuestion]="ex.questionText"
  [exampleAnswer]="ex.questionAnswers"
></example-component>
```

Then inside example-component:

```
<div *ngFor="let htmlexample of exampleAnswer">
  --this would be where my dynamic input field is--
<div>
```

Source: https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#configuring-the-parent-component

Comment: Great, this worked for me. Thanks a ton.  Now that I have my data displaying, I did  an [(ngModel)] on my dynamic input field, and I got back each input field auto-populated with the last object in the each array.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @JulieGladden Personally I would use Reactive Forms (https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) instead of [(ngModel)] because I think it's more structured and easier to make custom validations but if your required inputs are relatively small and does not need any complex validations, [(ngModel)] should be fine.

Comment: I am using Reactive Forms and I got the error "Multiple components match node with tagname <example-component> (using forEach and arr.push), so I was tried going with ngModel.  What do you think would be best route to go from here? Any examples you could push me towards? Thanks for your insight so far.

Comment: @JulieGladden Hmm.. Sorry it's kind of hard to make a comment on that without knowing more info/intended goals/target. It's not much of a help but for now all I can say is; to take a step back and look at the bigger picture and ask yourself if you're heading towards what you've originally envisioned. Good luck! You're already doing great by solving the problems you've encountered.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. It was invaluable! Have a great day. :)